# Disable form inputs when tab is not selected in jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-mobile

Can you please advise what would be the code to disable all form input elements in the jQuery Mobile tab that are not currently visible, given that

- there could be nested tabs with the same functionality
- when the tabs are just initiated, the inputs in the first tab should be enabled, others - disabled. Selecting another tab should switch enabled inputs to those visible
- there could be hidden inputs (input type "hidden"), select dropdown lists etc.
- there could be several forms on a page

Sorry I can't even imagine what to start from (confused by the docs being a novice)

Thanks!

See the tabs markup below. The `.serializeForm()` is written based on other advice here and is said to exclude the disabled controls, which I need

```html
<h3 class="ui-bar ui-corner-all">Действия</h3>
<div style="overflow: auto">
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" and data-expanded-icon="carat-u">
        <h3>Скрипт разговора</h3>
        <form>
            <p>
                <strong>
                    Вы должник?
                </strong>
            </p>
            <!--gen div id-->
            <div data-role="tabs">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#div2511-0-0" 
                               data-ajax="false" class="ui-corner-all">
                                да
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#div2511-0-1" 
                               data-ajax="false" class="ui-corner-all">

                                нет
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="div2511-0-0" style="padding: 0px; overflow: auto; border-width: thin">
                    <input type="hidden" name="isDebtor" value="1"/>
                    <div style="padding: 0px; overflow: auto; border-width: thin">
                        <p>
                            <strong>
                                каков ваш пол
                            </strong>
                        </p>
                        <label>Пол:</label>
                        <input name="gender" value="" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div style="padding: 0px; overflow: auto; border-width: thin">
                        <p>
                            <strong>
                                Обещаете оплатить?
                            </strong>
                        </p>
                        <!--gen div id-->
                        <div data-role="tabs">
                            <div data-role="navbar">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#div2511-2-0" 
                                           data-ajax="false" class="ui-corner-all">

                                            да
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#div2511-2-1" 
                                           data-ajax="false" class="ui-corner-all">
                                            нет
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div id="div2511-2-0" style="padding: 0px; overflow: auto; border-width: thin">
                                <input type="hidden" name="doesPromise" value="true"/>
                                <div style="padding: 0px; overflow: auto; border-width: thin">
                                    <p>
                                        <strong>
                                            Фиксируем обещание
                                        </strong>
                                    </p>
                                    ФИКСИРУЕМ!!!
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="div2511-2-1" style="padding: 0px; overflow: auto; border-width: thin">
                                <input type="hidden" name="doesPromise" value=""/>
                                <label>Причина:</label>
                                <select name="reason"  data-mini="true" class="ui-mini">
                                    <option value="noloan">
                                        Не брал кредит        
                                    </option>
                                    <option value="refuse">
                                        Немотивированный отказ        
                                    </option>
                                </select>    
                                <label>Уверенность:</label>
                                <select name="confidence" data-role="slider" data-mini="true">
                                    <option value="no">Нет</option>
                                    <option value="yes">Да</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>            
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="div2511-0-1" style="padding: 0px; overflow: auto; border-width: thin">
                    <input type="hidden" name="isDebtor" value=""/>
                </div>
            </div>            
            <p>
                <strong>
                    Сколько Вам лет?
                </strong>
            </p>
            <label>Возраст</label>
            <input name="ageFromForm"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Выполнить">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $("form").submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            console.log($(this).serializeForm());
        });
    });
</script>
```

**UPDATE** the business meaning of this is a talk script for a contact center. Choosing a tab is answering a question and in a tab there could be inputs and other tabs for subsequent questions. The script is defined by a tree-like json, I'd share this if it would be a fully javascript solution, but actually tabs are built by serverside java, so javascript people won't apreciate it =)

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is it to prevent those elements from being submitted?

Comment: Post _tabs_ html markup.

Comment: @Omar, it's generated, will try to ...

Comment: See my answer, comment there if this isn't quite what you're trying to do and I'll see if I can continue to help.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment you are trying to prevent the submission of elements that are no longer shown to the user. Elements with the attribute `disabled` will still submit, they just can't be changed by the user, which makes no sense because they're not visible anyway.

What you need to do is put the content of each tab inside it's own form

Psudo example:

```
<div id="tab1">
   <form>
      <!-- Form stuff here -->
   </form>
</div>
<div id="tab2">
   <form>
      <!-- Form stuff here -->
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I think it would be harder for me to collect data from severat forms to make an ajax call. And, tabs sets could be nested...

Answer (score -1):

You check if the element is visible on screen

http://www.teamdf.com/web/194/jquery-element-onscreen-visibility

once it is visible

```
$("input").prop('disabled', true);
$("input").prop('disabled', false);
```

make sure you are selecting the correct input

such as if the div `main` is in view then use `.main input` to select all input in class main

so `$(this)` selector will be helpful